# How can I display two Radio Buttons in the same row?

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, jpanel, layout-manager

I am a beginner in Java. I have been assigned the task of creating a Java window wherein which any user should be able to enter their personal data (name, last name,gender,etc) and then finally click on a submit button.

To create such window, I have added a `BorderLayout` and four panels using `GridLayout`. The main problem with my program, which keeps me stuck, is that I am unable to put two Radio Buttons in the same row. I have tried using both `GridLayout` and `TableLayout` inside a `JPanel` to solve the problem without any success.

This is the screenshot of how it looks:

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the "F" Radio Button should be placed next to the "M" Radio Button and not below.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Finestra extends JFrame

{

public Finestra ()

{
    super("Dati Utente");
    this.setBounds(300,50,400,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Panel panel1 = new Panel (new GridLayout(1,1));
    Panel panel2 = new Panel (new GridLayout(1,1));
    Panel panel3 = new Panel (new GridLayout(5,1));
    Panel panel4 = new Panel (new GridLayout(5,1));

    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
    panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
    panel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (100,200));
    panel4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (260,200));

    c.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    c.add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    c.add(panel3, BorderLayout.WEST);
    c.add(panel4, BorderLayout.EAST);

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel ("Personal Data");
    label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label1.setFont(new Font ("Open Sans",Font.BOLD,20));
    panel1.add(label1);

    JLabel label2 = new JLabel ("Name");
    label2.setFont(new Font ("Open Sans", Font.PLAIN,14));
    label2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,15,0,0));

    JLabel label3 = new JLabel ("Last Name");
    label3.setFont(new Font ("Open Sans", Font.PLAIN,14));
    label3.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,15,0,0));

    JLabel label4 = new JLabel ("Gender");
    label4.setFont(new Font ("Open Sans", Font.PLAIN,14));
    label4.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,15,0,0));

    JLabel label5 = new JLabel ("Hobby");
    label5.setFont(new Font ("Open Sans", Font.PLAIN,14));
    label5.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,15,0,0));

    JLabel label6 = new JLabel ("Nationality");
    label6.setFont(new Font ("Open Sans", Font.PLAIN,14));
    label6.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,15,0,0));

    panel3.add(label2);
    panel3.add(label3);
    panel3.add(label4);
    panel3.add(label5);
    panel3.add(label6);

    JTextField f1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField f2 = new JTextField();

    f1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180,30));
    f2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180,30));

    JPanel fp1 = new JPanel (), fp2 = new JPanel ();

    fp1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(15,0,0,0));
    fp2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(15,0,0,0));

    fp1.add(f1);
    fp2.add(f2);

    panel4.add(fp1);
    panel4.add(fp2);


    JRadioButton button1 = new JRadioButton("M"),button2 = new JRadioButton(("F"));


    button1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);  button2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    ButtonGroup bgroup1 = new ButtonGroup();

    bgroup1.add(button1); bgroup1.add(button2);

    panel4.add(button1); panel4.add(button2);


    setVisible(true);
}
```

How can I display two Radio Buttons in the same row?

Comment: I recommend using `JPanel`s rather than `Panel`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding `button1` and `button2` to `panel4`, add them to a new `JPanel` with a horizontal layout, and add the new `JPanel` to `panel4`.

```
JRadioButton button1 = new JRadioButton("M"),button2 = new JRadioButton(("F"));
button1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);  button2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
ButtonGroup bgroup1 = new ButtonGroup();
bgroup1.add(button1); bgroup1.add(button2);
JPanel radiobuttonpanel = new JPanel();
BoxLayout radiobuttonpanellayout = new BoxLayout(radiobuttonpanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
radiobuttonpanel.setLayout(radiobuttonpanellayout);
radiobuttonpanel.add(button1); radiobuttonpanel.add(button2);
panel4.add(radiobuttonpanel);
```

Comment: *"Please upvote"* It takes a certain amount of rep. points to be able to upvote, but if the OP keeps posting good, clear questions like this I guess it won't be long before they are able.